# kotlin: how to overload imported function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

i use assertj. among others it has functions `assertThat(int)` and `assertThat(Object)`. i would like to add my own function

```
fun <T> assertThat(flux: Flux<T>) = assertThat(flux.toStream())
```

but then it seems like i can't easily use it. when i declare the function outside of testing class `MyTest`, function call in tests binds to `assertThat(Object)` instead of `assertThat(Flux)`:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

//<----------- if declared here, doesn't work

class MyTest {

   //<----------- if declared here, all is ok

  @Test fun test() {
     assertThat(Flux.just(1)).containsExactly(1)
  }
}
```

what should i do to be able to use my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in an extra file and import it explicitely. I think it even helps to add the import when it's defined in your file, but IDE shows this import as unused.

Suggestion would be: define extension in `your/package/testutils.kt` and import it then:

`import your.package.assertThat`

Comment: yes, qualified import was needed. even if it's in the same file